# Criando novos dataframes e usando merge

Tags: python, pandas

Usei o yahooquery para importar uma série histórica de dados de 100 ativos negociados em bolsa.
Criei um dataframe com esses dados para um período de 6 meses:

```
df = tickers.history(period='6mo', interval="1d")
```

Só preciso da cotação de fechamento, portanto criei um dataframe chamado dfclose com esses dados e usei os ativos como índice.

```
dfclose = df.adjclose
dfclose = dfclose.reset_index(level=['symbol', 'date'])
```

Preciso agora Separar os ativos, de foram que não estejam na mesma coluna.
A solução que encontrei foi criar um data frame para cada ativo e depois uni-los usando a função merge.

```
df_AALR = dfclose[dfclose.symbol=='AALR3.SA']
df_YDUQ = dfclose[dfclose.symbol=='YDUQ3.SA']
df_PETR = dfclose[dfclose.symbol=='PETR4.SA']
```

```
pd.merge(df_AALR,df_YDUQ, on=['date']).merge(df_PETR, on='date')
```

Não sei se é a melhor solução.
Acho que seria possível criar uma função para criar os dataframes sem precisar digitar cada um e depois para uni-los.

A partir desse dataframe final, poderia prosseguir com as análises.
Estou no caminho certo?
Como criar essa função?

Comment: no pandas, quando você quer criar uma máscara para filtrar os dados usando mais de uma condição você pode usar & (para and) e | (para or). Eu não tenho seu DataFrame para verificar, mas acredito que você poderia fazer algo como `dfclose[dfclose.symbol=='AALR3.SA' | dfclose.symbol=='YDUQ3.SA']`

Comment: Não funcionou.Mensagem de erro: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'bool'

Comment: Então tem alguma coisa errada porque os dois tem que ser bool. Você pode copiar aqui como você testou?

Comment: df_final = dfclose[dfclose.symbol=='AALR3.SA']|dfclose[dfclose.symbol=='YDUQ3.SA']

Comment: Esse é o erro, você fez diferente do que eu sugeri. Copie esse `df_final = dfclose[dfclose.symbol=='AALR3.SA' | dfclose.symbol=='YDUQ3.SA']`

Comment: Obrigado mas segue dando erro: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]

Comment: Consegui usando a função pd.pivot_table.